# Can I convert a short form color (#123) into the long form (#112233) in stylus?

Tags: css, node.js, stylus

So I'm using an IE specific filter that requires the colours to be in the long form of 6 characters. But I have a thousand line stylesheet filled with calls to my function using the short form of 3 characters. So I'm hoping that it's possible to convert from the short to the long form from within the function. Any built-in or custom function will do. My function looks something like this:

```
td_gradient(color1, color2)
    background-color (color1 + (color2 - color1) / 2)
    background -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(color1), to(color2))
    background -webkit-linear-gradient(top, color1, color2)
    background -moz-linear-gradient(top, color1, color2)
    background -ms-linear-gradient(top, color1, color2)
    background -o-linear-gradient(top, color1, color2)
    filter s("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorstr='%s', EndColorstr='%s')", color1, color2)
```

The input colours look like `#333` and `#123`, but the Microsoft filter function requires `#333333` and `#112233`. Is there any way to satisfy it without editing every instance or a colour in my stylesheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the stylus source code, in lib/nodes/rgba.js, there's this method: RGBA.prototype.toString. On line 268, we find:

```
if (r[0] == r[1] && g[0] == g[1] && b[0] == b[1]) {
  return '#' + r[0] + g[0] + b[0];
} else {
  return '#' + r + g + b;
}
```

I experimented with building a function for you, but I can't seem to get the color back as a string, to do string manipulation. So the easiest way for you would probably be to patch `RGBA.prototype` and remove this shortening.

**UPDATE:** Ok, here is a function for you:

```
module.exports = function() {
    var hex = function(n) { return n.toString(16) };

    return function(style) {
        style.define('longColor', function(color) {
            return '#' + [color.r, color.g, color.b].map(hex).join("");
        });
    }
};
```

If you put it in a file `color.js`, you can use it with `stylus -u ./color.js`, or stylus' javascript API with `use`. Stylus usage:

```
td
  color longColor(#333)
```

Comment: This is probably the best way of accomplishing this, but I ended up going through my CSS and changing all instances of #333 to #343434 etc.

Comment: What about something like `(color.r << 16 | color.g << 8 | color.b).toString(16)` ?

Comment: this was really helpful but not exactly perfect for what I needed it for.  It removed any leading zeros and converted any double-zeros to a single 0.  Because I needed the full six-digit hex color for some old IE filters I had to alter this a bit. [https://gist.github.com/FranciscoG/b9d4ad3bcd1ccab168d7](https://gist.github.com/FranciscoG/b9d4ad3bcd1ccab168d7)